# How to fix If Statement that only returning False once one false is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three spreadsheets in total. My primary spreadsheet contains all the important details as described below in the first photo. The combined files sheet does exactly as it sounds. Since there were multiple entries with the same part number but different photos it takes the part number and used a text join to combine all the same part numbers photos with it's files on a single line delimited by a comma. The pivotal table just allows me to visually see part numbers and its associated files.

[This is the primary sheet that contains all the details like part description, pricing, specifications, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eII1S.jpg)

Currently on the primary sheet when I use an if statement to reference the comma separated file names, I'm running into a case where a part number exists on the primary sheet, but does not exist on the combined sheet. Because the part number doesn't exist it will return false, which is correct. However, it will get stuck returning false forever after one is found. So once that first one failed the logical test and returned false everything after is returned false despite having logical tests on the if statements being true after that single false occurrence.

[Pivot Table to show looking up a partnumber that doesn't exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X75N4.jpg)

[This table uses the pivot table and text join to place the file images together delimited by a comma.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaf2E.jpg)

Below is the if statement used, even adding a false return value of "" or something like .png no matter what it will get stuck return that false value for everything after.

```
=IF([@punctuatedPartNumber]=Table7[@PunctuatedPartNumber],Table7[@[Combined Files]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

I think the problem may be using `[@xxxx]` in the **IF** function. You can use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the corresponding CombineFiles for each PartNumber.

Your function may look like the following:

```
=INDEX(Table7[Combined Files],MATCH(A1,Table7[PunctuatedPartNumber],0))
```

Replace `A1` with the cell address of the first punctuated part number on your primary sheet.

Let me know if there is any problem. Cheers :)

Comment: I edited my initial question to hopefully clarify my issue. Even with a false statement I still get stuck where it returns false for everything after that one item is found to be false because it doesn't exist. Many part numbers after that have photos that do exist. I believe it's an issue with my if statement because I'm looking up a part number from one table to another table that doesn't contain that part number. I think because the part number doesn't exist it gets stuck in a forever false loop not actually running the if statement? I have no clue, excel is not my strong suit.

Comment: @Jason please see my updated solution. I think you can use INDEX+MATCH to return the combined files for each part number.

Comment: @Jason you are welcome. My experience is that using `[@xxxx]`  [Structured Reference](https://exceljet.net/glossary/structured-reference) can sometimes cause problems when you want to refer to cell value instead of a range of values (either row or column). So when referring to cell value I normally use the actual cell address.